# Google plus one : Does anyone know how it specify which image to display?

Tags: javascript, google-plus

when i press the button + google i have a thumbnail (picture of a site) randomly generated, Does anyone know how it specify which image to display ?

Answer (score 4):

Google has a support answer for it. https://developers.google.com/+/plugins/+1button/#plus-snippet

Basically, it goes like Microdata, OpenGraph, Meta and, if all else fail, page content.

Comment: The link that mmhan provided is the official documentation.

Just to clarify one thing: schema.org markup is the preferred way to specify the photo.

Comment: The link in the answer works perfectly fine but it redirects (though it didn't do that when this answer was provided). Redirect URL is   https://developers.google.com/+/plugins/+1button/#plus-snippet

Comment: A better documentation link might be to https://developers.google.com/+/plugins/snippet/ which describes how to actually mark up the target page.

Answer (score 1):

Facebook provided an **open microformat standard** about this and called it: [**OpenGraph**](http://ogp.me/).
I would find it *strange if google ignored it altogether*. Haven't tested that, though.

Opengraph uses an `og:image` attribute.

Try something like this:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="http://example.com/post/13371312/picture.jpg" />
```

in the `<head>` section.

If it doesn't work, I'd suggest also checking out on the Google [Opensocial](http://docs.opensocial.org/) site. (if you didn't already)

It's a pretty labyrinthic site and more about apps and oauth interaction, but you could get lucky.

Answer (score 0):

I believe Google hasn't provided a way to select the image that is going to be selected like Facebook does with the  tag on the head of the HTML.